# Laravel 5.3 scheduler Runs once on Windows then ends without any further processing

Tags: php, windows, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-scheduler

OS: Windows 8.1

Laravel-version: 5.3.15

Hello,

I'm having a bit of trouble getting Laravel's scheduler to properly run on on my machine and **STAY RUNNING** in a way where I can see some sort of output to indicate that it's actually working. Every time I run `php artisan schedule:run` it calls any listed commands once and then just dies. It doesn't repeat or anything. Example attempt below:

**The Code:**

[image]

**The Result When Trying to Run the Scheduler:**

[image]

**What I've tried:**

I've tried multiple suggested fixes from the link below and some are actually referenced throughout stackoverflow as well. Including adding a batch file, setting php's path in my system veriables etc etc. as suggested in the link below by Kryptonit3:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/running-schedulerun-on-windows

However, nothing works. Even in the "Windows Task Scheduler" tool it will just run once, end any further processing in the CLI and then close the window. There is no actual indication that this scheduler is running in the background indefinitely (Sort-of like a background job only without the queues).

**Questions:**

1 - With no indication (the echoed "I am Scheduled") how do I know if this is actually working?

2 - Why does attempting to run this command die after it successfully completes once.

3 - Does my Laravel Version have anything to do the scheduler not running permenently when I try using `php artisan schedule:run` in the CLI or windows task scheduler?

4 - Mainly what I'm trying to accomplish here is every minute the system would scan a single DB table's field. How do I accomplish this?

5 -  Can someone please give me some clarification on this? Or point me in the right direction so that I can get this thing really running indefinitely without it just ending after the first run?

**Note:** I do not want to use Laravel Forge or any other external service for something so simple. That would be overkill and unecessary I feel.

Answer (score 0):

after doing some rather serious digging I found that all of what **Kryptonit3** had said in his step by step answer that I referenced was correct. However, I did not know I needed to restart my computer after creating a new task with the Windows Task Scheduler. I thought this would happen automatically. Would've saved me 2 days of debugging had I'd of known but regardless, if someone else comes across this similar problem they will know to reboot the computer.

Reference:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/running-schedulerun-on-windows